# auto-mapping of element in view to model from type dateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date-format, asp.net-mvc-5

I have value of text box with some date time format (the default that DatePicker supplies - for example - 01/23/2014).

```
  <input type="text" name="OrderDate" value="" id="OrderDate" class="datepicker field field119 datepicker-init" />
```

I have correlative Property in the model class with the same name and ID as the element in the view.

```
 public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
```

at this point everything is matched and once submit I get the right value in my controller.

Now - I'd like to change the default DatePicker format -
for example:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
                minDate: 0,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            });
```

and I fail to "explain" the model proprty how to serlizae the text box value - instead I get the default DateTime and not my time.

the question : how to change the text box date format that the DateTime property will know how to serialize that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is how you get this working.

Firstly jQuery UI formats the date you need using `dd/mm/y`, so you need to change your javascript to this:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
                minDate: 0,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/y'
            });
```

See jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hutchonoid/Fa8Xx/1376/

Then you need to format the model date in the view, you can do this like so:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderDate, String.Format("{0:dd/M/yy}", Model.OrderDate),
  new { @class = "datepicker field field119 datepicker-init" })
```

This works nicely with model binding to when posting the date back to the server.

Comment: will try that soon - you think that will be acceptable by the Property of the class? Do I need to "tell" the proprty the value format it would get (in attribute or something)?

Comment: thanks! I got some exception in the view class, I'll look into: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_de2tc4rb.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: No probs. Are you passing the model back to the view with a populated date?

Comment: yep, well actually the framework does it - all I did is just declared on a function that gets this type of object and the matching is done underneath : [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult OrderSubmit(OrderDetails orderDetails).....maybe the format is incorrect?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45664/discussion-between-user1025852-and-hutchonoid)

Comment: Hi, sorry I can't at the moment as I'm on my phone browser.